# ORA-0131 :insufficient privileges DEBUG CONNECT SESSION

Tags: oracle, debugging, plsql

I got this error message "ORA-0131 :insufficient privileges DEBUG CONNECT SESSION" trying to start debug PL/SQL script using PL/SQL Developer.

Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.7.0

I'm a part of admin group. Is this privileges necessary?

```
grant DEBUG CONNECT SESSION to =<bobens_83-here_goes_your_db-username>
```

Comment: This is off-topic and belongs on [dba.se]

Comment: @JimGarrison I disagree - IMHO this is a question about debugging and therefore on-topic on SO.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you mentioned , its problem of privileges.

Quoted from this [site](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01031_insufficient_privileges.htm)

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
>
> Cause: An attempt was made to change the current username or password
> without the appropriate privilege. This error also occurs if attempting to
> install a database without the necessary operating system privileges.
> When Trusted Oracle is configure in DBMS MAC, this error may occur if
> the user was granted the necessary privilege at a higher label than the
> current login.
>
> Action: Ask the database administrator to perform the operation or grant
> the required privileges. For Trusted Oracle users getting this error
> although granted the appropriate privilege at a higher label, ask the
> database administrator to re-grant the privilege at the appropriate label.

If you working on debug it should work

```
grant DEBUG CONNECT SESSION to <bobens_83-here_goes_your_db-username>
```